# Powershell Mail Script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to create a powershell mailer script that will receive parameter(mail_ids) as argument from Jenkins. The first argument is to be skipped. From second argument all are maild_ids, those will get mail.
Mail notification is successful if I'm using hard coded way, but failing if I try to pass it as argument. The script is written below, also the error is mentioned too.

What is wrong in the below:

```
foreach ([string[]] $arg1 in `$args| select -skip 1`)
{
   Send-MailMessage -To $arg1 "XYZ Build" -Body "$Mail_body" -smtpserver XYZ-ABCDE.XYZ.XYZ
}
```

Error:

```
Missing variable name after foreach. At C:\Deploy\SmartCM\sendmail_scm.ps1:16 char:10
+ foreach ( <<<< [string[]] $arg1 in `$args| select -skip 1`)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (VariableToken:TokenId) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingVariableNameAfterForeach
```

Comment: The error message tells you that it is looking for `$` (as variable start) right after opening `(`.  Try `foreach ($arg1 in \`$args| select -skip 1\`)`. Otherwise than that you need to provide more information on what you are trying to achive.

Comment: I am trying to make a script that is getting input as argument from Jenkins. First argument is to be skipped as that one is file name, rest are mail_ids. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!!

Comment: That is much better.  Please update your question with the additional information.  Like what you have and where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my purpose using the following script:

```
    foreach ($arg in $args[1..($args.length -1)])
{
    [string[]]$toAddress=$arg
    Write-Host "${toAddress}"
    Send-MailMessage -To $toAddress -From jenkins@XYZ.com -Subject "XYZ Build" -Body "$Mail_body" -smtpserver XYZ-smtpint.XYZ.ABCD
}
```

Thanks everyone for support!!